# Expectation value of position operator $X$ in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform

I'm solving the following question:
If $\psi(p)$ is the wavefunction of a particle in momentum space, write down the expression for the expectation value of the position operator $\langle x\rangle$?

I got an expression in terms of $\psi(p)$. I just want to know if there is some neat examples when the result is zero.

Comment: what do you mean: "there is some neat results like zero or one." ??

Comment: Note that questions asking for examples (typically called *list-based questions*) are considered off topic for being overly broad. Could you narrow down the question to something more focused?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the symmetries of you wave function, then for instance the $\langle x\rangle=0$ if $\phi(x)=\phi(-x)$ (provided the integration region is symmetric around $x=0$). Actaully since $x$ is purely real, the requirement can be relaxed to $|\phi(x)|=|\phi(-x)|$.

To translate this to $\psi(p)$ we make use of the Fourier relation between the two
 $$ \psi\left(p\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dp\, e^{-ixp}\phi\left(x\right).$$

Now equating $\phi(x)=\phi(-x)$ we have 
 $$ \psi\left(p\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dx\, e^{-ixp}\phi\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dx\, e^{-ixp}\phi\left(-x\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\int dx\, e^{-ix\left(-p\right)}\phi\left(x\right)=\psi\left(-p\right)
$$
 which means that $\psi\left(p\right)=-\psi\left(-p\right)$.

I'll leave the more generic case as a exercise.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: You are so right. Extended the answer.